# Admob Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: admob

My source:

```
_admobBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
_admobBanner.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
_admobBanner.rootViewController = self;
_admobBanner.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_admobBanner];

[NSArray arrayWithObjects:GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];
[_admobBanner loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Add framework 
StoreKit.framework 
SystemConfiguration.framework 
MessageUI.framework 
AudioToolbox.framework

But when linking my application I see an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADIdentifierUtilities.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone provide pointers as to where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against AdSupport.framework to provide `ASIdentifierManager`.